# stop executing the example() in R

Tags: r

In R we can use example() to go through the examples of a function, in many functions you have to press enter button (or maybe any other key) to jump to the next example. But how can I just directly skip all the rest examples (or stop the example from continuing) if after watching some examples, I have found what I need and just want to go back to my code?

Comment: In the R GUI you can just type Escape  (the character)

Comment: OK, yes, it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can just type `escape` / `esc`